# Receiving error when trying to use ~/.ssh/config "ssh: Could not resolve hostname"

Tags: linux, ssh, dns, centos, proxy

I have scoured the internet for a solution, but no solution is working for me! 
I am trying to create a bastion server with a public AWS EC2 instance that will connect to a private EC2 instance.

Below is my`~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host bastion
   Hostname <instanceIP>
   User ec2-user
   IdentityFile <keypairPath>
   ProxyCommand none
 Host private
   Hostname <privateIP>
   User ec2-user
   IdentityFile <keypairPath>
   ProxyCommand ssh bastion -W %h:%p
```

When I attempt to run `ssh bastion` I receive this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bastion: Name or service not known
```

I can connect with `ssh -F config bastion` with root (but not with local user), but I do not want to put that argument every time since I have seen that the `-F` is not required.

I also am not able to connect with `ssh -F config private` as root. The error states:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bastion: Name or service not known
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I changed up the last line in the `/.ssh/config` file to

```
ProxyCommand ssh -F config bastion -W %h:%p
```

but that brings back this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
Killed by signal 1
```

What am I doing wrong with my config file, and how can I ssh with the local profile and not root?

Comment: `<instanceIP>` and `<keypairPath>` are both placeholders for the actual information, rather than literal, correct? What happens if you run `ssh -i <keyparePath> ec2-user@<instanceIP> echo test`? That is, do what the configured bastion host should be doing, without actually using that config block.

Answer (score 1):

> I can connect with ssh -F config bastion with root (but not with local user),

Sounds very much like

- the permissions or ownership of your `~/.ssh/` directory or the `~/.ssh/config` file are incorrect, e.g. the file is owned by root instead of the actual user who's trying to connect, or it is not readable by the user; or
- you're putting the file in the wrong user's `~/.ssh` (note that *ssh* ignores $HOME and always determines the home directory by UID).

(The last note means you cannot use the same config file both normally and with *sudo*, not that you should need to do that anyway.)